# git not synchronizing local repo with remote branch

Tags: git, git-pull

I created a new branch from the master called `remove-maven-3`. Surprisingly it doesn't have a file called pom.xml on local, but if I check it on remote github.com, it's there. 
The following is the result of the command git pull:

```
git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=agbi-code/<branch> remove-maven-3
```

This seems weird don't have any idea what might be going wrong.

Comment: Does it not tell you what to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-pull%5D+There+is+no+tracking+information+for+the+current+branch